# Change windows terminal colors to reflect Git status

Tags: git, cmder, windows-terminal

I'm using [Cmdr](https://cmder.net/) as my console emulator for Windows 10, and I really love it, it came with Laragon, the portable development environment.

What I like most about Cmdr is that there's a version that comes "integrated" with Git, it provides most of Unix commands, when you're using Git, besides the prompt it shows the branch you're working in, like:

```
c:\whatever\ (master)
>
```

Not only that, it changes the color to red if you have changes pending commit, or white if there are no changes pending

Now I want to use new Windows Terminal, just for the fun of learning new things, lots of people talks wonders about it. But I want to emulate like what Cmder does, so my prompt shows the branch I'm in, and if there are pending changes.

Is it possible? If so... how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://medium.com/@techpreacher/using-git-bash-with-the-microsoft-terminal-bd1f71fa17a1

Comment: Ufff... yeah looks like it will work. I guess long days are gone since the `%PROMPT=whatever`, I don't even remember how it was. It used to be a lot simplier!! --- Thanks a lot!!!